# IOS In-app Purchase No transactionReceipt

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app

I am implementing an in-app-purchase for my ios app. I already received some successful purchases and upgraded their account to premium. Everything was well and good until I received a certain response from apple (it happened three times already) which has no transactionReceipt field. I'm not sure how I can validate it since the transactionReceipt is what I use to validate the transaction. I recently received the reports from Apple and confirmed that there was actually a transaction. How can I validate the transaction without the transactionReceipt? Or is there a way I could get the transactionReceipt using the transactionId or something?

PS: It's an auto-renewing subscription. Sorry if I didn't specify it early.

PS: Since it's an auto-renewing subscription, I don't only need the receipt to upgrade the account to premium, but also to identify when it's going to expire.

Comment: Have you tried to refresh your receipts using SKReceiptRefreshRequest API ? Are they returning same receipt without transaction details ?

Comment: Have you checked [[NSBundle mainBundle] appStoreReceiptURL]? I have implemented non-consumable type and it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prompt the user to restore purchase when you find a response with no transaction receipt.

This way you will get the purchase receipt of the user's latest transaction.

Comment: You can't restore consumable type purchase.

Comment: Well its not clear in the question that which type of purchase is Giovanni using. So in case it is not a consumable purchase, I believe this approach might help.

Comment: It's an auto-renewing subscription. Sorry if I didn't specify it.

Comment: In that case, @GiovanniLobitos, prompting the user to restore purchase might help you in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try this.